# What is the component name of the following image?

Tags: android

[image: grab component for sorting the list]

**Can you people see the common icon at the left of this list . If we hold and drag that icon then we can manually arrange the list. I want to know the name of this component and any example links (if available) to achieve this.**

Thanks,

Comment: this image is picked up from the astrid tasks application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its drag and drop list view you can find and example

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html

> This project code is simply to share a simple working drag and drop list since I was unable to find one elsewhere on the web. If you add any extensions to this simple project I would like to hear about it in the comments.

or

You can also try Mark Murphy's

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist

> To work with TouchListView in your own project, place the library project somewhere and update your project to reference the library project (via Eclipse, via android update lib-project, etc.). Then, add a com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView widget to your XML layout file.